# How to rename a field in CnosDB?

Tags: sql, cnosdb

I have following data in CnosDB per [this doc](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_sample.html):

```
> select * from air where visibility > 70
name: air
time                 pressure station     temperature visibility
----                 -------- -------     ----------- ----------
2021-08-31T16:00:00Z 78       LianYunGang 63          71
2021-08-31T16:06:00Z 58       XiaoMaiDao  77          79
```

How can I rename the field name similar to [MySQL style](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/ja/alter-table.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CnosDB currently does not support alter modification of field names.

Now only supports adding columns, deleting columns, modifying column types and encodings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).